# How to retrieve all values from a column in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x

I am wondering how to retrieve all values stored in a column in `mongoDB`, and put them in a list. `find()` only get all the fields, and specify `<field>: <value>` isn't an option as well.

Comment: Please show us sample documents with the expected output.

Comment: You have to convert it to list in you programming language like in Python

           list(data)

Answer (score 1):

If you are expecting to retrieve unique values in a column then distinct should work for you. Following is the syntax :
db.yourcollection.distinct("yourfield");

Learn more about distinct [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/)